# 1 error prohibited this stage from being saved: Project must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a project scaffold which save name of the project and i have created association one to many with stage scaffold. but after creating project when i try to create stage i get this error-" Project must exist "

project.rb

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  validates :project_name, presence: true
  has_many :stages
end
```

stage.rb

```
class Stage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  validates :stage, :planned_start_date, :planned_end_date, :responsibility, presence: true
  has_many :tasks
end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "project_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "stages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "stage"
    t.date "planned_start_date"
    t.date "planned_end_date"
    t.date "actual_start_date"
    t.date "actual_end_date"
    t.string "responsibility"
    t.boolean "status"
    t.float "finance"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_stages_on_project_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a new `Stage`. you need to provide a `Project` because you have association belongs_to and has_many between `Project` and `Stage`. So, As per the schema you need to provide a `project_id` in Stage.

you can create Stage like this.

```
@project = Project.find(your_porject_id)
@stage = project.stages.create(your_stage_params)
```

OR

```
@project = Project.find(your_porject_id)
@stage = project.stages.new(your_stage_params)
@stage.save
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: If project is optional, simply add "optional: true" to the belongs_to